# Joomla how edit registration message in joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

I want to edit registration message, I used Joomla 3 template beez 3
I want to change the style (css) message Registration 3 joomla COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_VERIFY. I know that changing Registration message content from the en-FR.com-users.ini (French), but how to change the colors of text and rear map and make hyperlinks and separate sentences with white line

Comment: Actually you should use the Language Override in the language manager of Joomla's Administrator, that will make your change persist after updates. The rest of the questions is not clear, please add some detail and sample code and tests you have performed.

Answer (score 1):

no need to hack ;)

In the back-end of your site :

1. Under the « Extensions » menu select « Language(s) » sub-menu.
2. In the left panel choose « Overrides »
3. In the filter select your languages that you want to override
4. Select the « New » button to create your override
5. At the right part you'll see « Search text you want to change. »
6. You can search for a « Constant » with « COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_VERIFY » or you can search the « value » like the sentence that you want to replace.
7. After selection your constant or value you will have to enter in the « Text » field your alternative text and click « Save & Close »

By following this links you can find more visual examples :

- (French) http://cinnk.com/joomla/3/trucs-et-astuces/comment-surcharger-une-langue
- (English) https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/languge-manager/
- (English) https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla